# NullPointerException in MediaPlayer after pressing the home button and reopening the app

Tags: android, android-mediaplayer, media-player

This is my code, I want to keep music playing when the app is in background. And I want to be able to pause it when I re-open the app. The music should play in the background, but for some reason media player returns null pointer when I re-open it. So, when I pause it, it crashes.

```
public void play(View view) {
    if (status) {
        status = false;
        requestRecordAudioPermission();//audio permission
        startPlay();//start mediaplayer
    } else {
        status = true;
        mediaPlayer.pause();
    }
}

public void startPlay() {
    mediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer();
    try {
        mediaPlayer.setDataSource(URL_LINK);
        mediaPlayer.prepare();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        Toast.makeText(HomeActivity.this, "CAN'T PLAY!",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
    mediaPlayer.start();
}
```

Why Media Player returns null after pressing the home button and reopening the app?

Thanks for help

Comment: Improved grammar, clarified the question

Answer (score 0):

If you are streaming audio from an url then try to load the Media Player asynchronously.

```
    String url = "YOUR_URL";
    MediaPlayer myMediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer();
    myMediaPlayer.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
    try {
        myMediaPlayer.setDataSource(url);
        myMediaPlayer.prepareAsync();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "mp3 not found", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

    myMediaPlayer.setOnPreparedListener(new MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer player) {
            player.start();
        }

    });
```